# How can I create a table readable in excel? C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have some data in c#, and I want to put this data into Excel. I figure the easiest way is to export it as XML since Excel reads xml files.

What's the easiest way to do this? I don't know what format the xml needs to be in for Excel to read it. I want a simple table of data (headers, data, and totals, although the totals I can simply generate in c# rather than have excel do it).

There might also be a better way without using xml, but simplest is best and definitely no 3rd party stuff...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice intro at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excelxmlspreadsheet.aspx that should get you started writing basic XML spreadsheets.

You may want to reconsider using 3rd party tools; there are some nice ones out there with good licenses that will make your life a lot easier.

I've used http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/ previously to write simple data to an Excel spreadsheet.  It outputs right into the Excel XML format you mention.

I've also had success using [Apache POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html), though not its most recent incarnation (it lacked Office 2007 support at the time).  You can use [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to recompile the Java library into a .NET library, and you're good to go.

Comment: I figured out how to write xml documents so I can have lovely formatting. There is such a small amount of documentation on the subject but I figured enough out to produce a very nice formatted table.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to dump data into a CSV format, and open it with Excel!

This can take 10 lines of code in Python.

I am sure you can figure this out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA011019641033.aspx) explains how to open an manipulate XML data in Excel 2003, and [this video explains the same for 2007](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0S2CQd46C4).

Or, as lpthnc has suggested, you can export the data as CSV which Excel has no problem handling.

Answer (score 1):

Write a CSV reader writer if you want a good compromise between human and machine readable in a Windows environment

Loads into Excel too.

There's a discussion about it here:

http://knab.ws/blog/index.php?/archives/3-CSV-file-parser-and-writer-in-C-Part-1.html

That is a C# article not a C one.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach if your needs are basic: you can put it into HTML with a table representing your spreadsheet and just name your html file .xls. That way you don't need to worry about what a comma will do to you and can provide a basic level of formatting as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to do similar things in the past. The easiest way I have found to do it is to export directly from my application to excel:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Populate a datatable, datagrid, dataset, etc. and iteerate through the results and output to excel. The exmaple below is in VB but can be easily altered for your purposes and uses a dataset:

```
Public Sub ExcelExport(ByVal objDataSet As System.Data.DataSet)

        Try
            Dim l_ofd As New SaveFileDialog

            l_ofd.Filter = "Microsoft 2007 Excel File (*.xls)|*.xls"

            If (l_ofd.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                If (objDataSet.Tables.Count > 0) Then

                    Dim myExcel As ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()

                    myExcel.Visible = _ShowWorkBook

                    Dim wb1 As Workbook = myExcel.Workbooks.Add("")

                    Dim ws1 As Worksheet = CType(wb1.Worksheets.Add, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

                    ws1.Name = _WorkSheetName

                    For indx As Integer = 0 To objDataSet.Tables(_DataSetName).Columns.Count - 1
                        ws1.Cells(1, indx + 1) = objDataSet.Tables(_DataSetName).Columns.Item(indx).ToString
                    Next

                    Dim rowID As Integer = 2
                    Dim dr As DataRow
                    For Each dr In objDataSet.Tables(_DataSetName).Rows
                        Dim colID As Integer = 1
                        Dim data As Object
                        For Each data In dr.ItemArray
                            ws1.Cells(rowID, colID) = data.ToString()
                            colID += 1
                        Next
                        rowID += 1
                    Next

                    Dim fileName As String = l_ofd.FileName

                    wb1.SaveAs(fileName)
                    wb1.Close()

                    myExcel.Workbooks.Close()
                    myExcel.Quit()

                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcel)
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws1)
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb1)

                    ws1 = Nothing
                    wb1 = Nothing
                    myExcel = Nothing
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("No data present to export")
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that presents another approach using the OpenXML SDK 2.0:

http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/7937.aspx

It demonstrates the use of [ExtremeML](http://www.extrememl.com/) - a 100% managed code extension library that greatly simplifies the programmatic creation of Excel content from .NET languages. The [tutorial series](http://www.extrememl.com/index.php/knowledge-center/tutorials) covers a broad range of scenarios.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of ExtremeML.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a DataTable, I just wrote some code to transfer it to Excel. First you need an Excel reference.

```
        //Just a test DataTable
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("Col1"),new DataColumn("Col2") });
        table.Rows.Add("row1col1", "row1col2");
        table.Rows.Add("row2col1", "row2col2");

        //create Excel Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass s = new ApplicationClass();
        Workbook w = s.Workbooks.Add(""); //create new Workbook
        Worksheet ws = w.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;  //get active sheet.

        //COPY COLUMN HEADERS
        int startCol = 1;
        int startRow = 1;
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            //copy columns in the first row
            ((Range)ws.Cells[startRow, startCol]).Value2 = col.ColumnName;
            startCol++;
        }

        //COPY ROWS
        startRow = 2; //start 2nd row
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            startCol = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                ((Range)ws.Cells[startRow, startCol]).Value2 = row[col].ToString();
                startCol++;
            }
            startRow++;
        }

        //start EXCEL
        s.Visible = true;
```

Comment: And you need excel on the machine. This is perfectly ok for client side. OP did not indicate if this was server side or not. I would stay away from this server side if this is going to be called regularly as the excel process will inevitably cause issues. Been there, done that.

Comment: @Jim, yep OP asked a simple question, i showed him some code..perhaps someone else will benefit from this code as is.